# Change Gridview right side sider in Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I'm working on a wallpaper application in andriod. I just want change the right slider of a Gridview. I just want something like this.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSiO9.jpg)

Comment: If you want remove then set this property in your gridview `android:scrollbars="none"` and if you want to scroll horizontally then use this https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

Answer (score 0):

You should set rotationY for gridview 180 and rotation your layout inside of gridview 180.
with this instruction gridview being right to left and scrollbar going to right.
hope help you.